# custom post types category break

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I've created a new custom post type and displayed all those posts on an archive page. Everything is working fine till now. But when I try to add a new category to the built in posts, the archive custom post type page breaks and I get a 404 error. Does anybody got this problem until now? What am I doing wrong or what can be wrong here?

This is all the code:
function my_custom_post_people() {

```
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Our People', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Lawyer', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'our-people' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Lawyer' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Lawyer' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Lawyer' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Lawyers' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Lawyer' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Lawyer' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No lawyer found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No lawyer found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Our Lawyers'
);

$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds our lawyers and lawyer specific data',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments','custom-fields', 'page-attributes' ),
    'has_archive'   => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'taxonomies'   => array('people_category', 'post_tag') 
);
register_post_type( 'our-people', $args );
```

}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_people' );

function my_taxonomies_people() {

```
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Lawyer Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Lawyer Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Lawyer Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Lawyer Categories' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Lawyer Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Lawyer Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Lawyer Category' ), 
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Lawyer Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Lawyer Category' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Lawyer Category' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Lawyer Categories' ),
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
);

register_taxonomy( 'people_category', 'our-people', $args );
```

}

add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_people', 0 );

Thanks

Comment: Please share the setup code of your custom post type

Comment: Maybe your category slug and post type slug matches , try to check they need to be different and also refresh your permalinks by re-saving  them

Comment: added the code above. Tried also redeclaring the slug, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: I updated wordpress from wp 4.0.2 to 4.2.2 and that seems to have fixed the problem.